# Cannot convert argument 1 from 'const TImpl' to 'TImpl &&'

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I have the following templates:

```
template <class TImpl>
class PrinterImpl
{
public:
    void PrintImpl(const TImpl& t)
    {
        std::cout << "&" << t << "\n";
        PrintImplPrivate(t);
    }

    void PrintImpl(TImpl&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "&&" << std::forward<TImpl>(t) << "\n";
        PrintImplPrivate(std::forward<TImpl>(t));
    }

private:
    void PrintImplPrivate(TImpl&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "private print implementation" << t << "\n";
    }
};

template <class T>
class Printer
{
public:    
    void Print(const T& t)
    {
        m_printerImpl.PrintImpl(t);
    }

    void Print(T&& t)
    {
        m_printerImpl.PrintImpl(std::forward<T>(t));
    }

private:
    PrinterImpl<T> m_printerImpl; 
};
```

I am not able to build this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    Printer<int> p;
    p.Print(x);
}
```

because of this error:

> error C2664: 'void PrinterImpl<T>::PrintImplPrivate(TImpl &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const TImpl' to 'TImpl &&'

Is there a way to not implement a private method twice for r-val reference and const reference, as intended above in the `PrinterImpl` class?

Comment: Why do you even have two overloads? Why not make just one, `const T &`? Or if you do need them, change `PrintImplPrivate` to accept `const T &`?

Comment: `PrintImplPrivate(std::forward<TImpl>(t));` should be `PrintImplPrivate(std::move(t));` since it's not a forwarding reference - and like @HolyBlackCat mentioned, just make `void PrintImplPrivate(const TImpl& t)`

Comment: For a proper [pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) you should begin by making `PrinterImpl` a private structure inside `Printer`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with implementing something twice. You're attempting to bind an lvalue reference to a const reference, which is not allowed. Use `PrintImplPrivate((TImpl)t);` instead. As far as removing duplicated code, that would be a different question to ask, there are some techniques that can be tried, but, first, one needs to resolve this issue first. One would be for the private method to also take a const reference as a parameter, if so then it would be possible to have a single implementation of the forwarding function.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to not implement a private method twice for r-val reference and const reference, as intended above in the PrinterImpl class?

Yes, just make `PrintImplPrivate` a **template**(member function template) so that the parameter becomes a forwarding reference as shown below.

Also note the use of default argument in the template parameter so that we don't have to specify it when calling the member function. Note that we can also restrict `U` to be the same as class template parameter `TImpl` but that is left as an exercise.

```
template <class TImpl>
class PrinterImpl
{
public:
    //other code exactly as before
private:
    //added this template parameter clause with default parameter
    template<typename U = TImpl> 
    void PrintImplPrivate(U&& t)
    {
        std::cout << "private print implementation" << t << "\n";
    }
};
int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    Printer<int> p;
    p.Print(x); //works now
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f1a6bfefc)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please explain or give a resource to study what happens under the hood when adding the "default parameter"?

Comment: @Dom Here is a one [source](https://www.ibm.com/docs/kk/zos/3.1.0?topic=only-default-arguments-template-parameters-c) to get started. Here is another [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/67xbT48cj) that I created to demonstrate the use of default argument in template parameter that will be helpful for reading this answer. You're welcome. There are many other resources but the above should give an idea since comment section has a word limit here and this is not directly related to the question, so I can't add this in the answer.

Comment: Now I see. The template parameter turns the argument into a forwarding reference (from r-value reference).

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the uses of the auto keyword.

```
void PrintImplPrivate(auto && t) {
    std::cout << "private print implementation" << t << "\n";
}
```

Reference collapsing rules will make it accept a `const TImpl &` and a `TImpl &&`